# metric path not allowing a format like /? output = text (PROMETHEUS)

Tags: yaml, prometheus, monitoring

We are trying to track targets using urls like the following:

http://example.com:1234/?output=text

```
sample config:

     - job_name: test-1
         metrics_path: /?output=text
         scheme: http
         static_configs:
         - targets:
           - example.com:1234
```

However, Prometheus (from Grafana) converts "?" for "%3F" during extraction and as a result gets 404. Would anyone know to help me identify a solution for this. Tried to use parameters, but a key and value structure is needed.

Comment: Can you clarify "tried to use parameters, but a key and value structure is needed" There is a params attribute you can apply to the job config to specify URL parameters in key/value form: like "output:text"